# SQL: Merging results from two tables into one result

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I've begun to dive into joins/apply/unions, etc and there's one concept I don't think I understand in this, and I was hoping I could be helped out. Let's say I have two tables, tabone and tabtwo.

In tabone:

| product | color |
| --- | --- |
| Eggs | Tan |
| Milk | White |

In tabtwo:

| product | price |
| --- | --- |
| Eggs | 1.50 |
| Milk | 2.00 |

I'd like to learn how to write query which will in a single result show me the product, color, and price for any given product.

Example output I'd like:

| product | price | color |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Eggs | 1.50 | Tan |

From what I've gathered so far, I don't see quite how a join or union can achieve this in one result. All of my testing gives me multiple columns with the color for example not merging. I'd appreciate some help on this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *join* the two tables in at least 3 ways.

You can *inner join*, use a *correlated subquery* or *apply* a correlation. All work as expected provided the *product* is unique:

```
select t1.product, t2.price, t1.color
from tabone t1
join tabtwo t2 on t2.product = t1.product;

select product,
  (select price from tabtwo t2 where t2.product = t1.product) price,
  color
from tabone t1;

select t1.product, t2.price, t1.color
from tabone t1
cross apply (
  select price 
    from tabtwo t2 
    where t2.product = t1.product
) t2;
```

Comment: Hi Stu, this is great! Thank you very much! And just as a clarification, let's say I only wanted a specific item to be merged. Using your first example, I could simply utilize a WHERE clause after the ON clause, correct?

Comment: Correct, `where t1.product=...`

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a performance discrepancy between the join and cross apply clauses you've used? From my research, cross apply should be used when no very basic join condition can be used. In this example it doesn't seem like there'd be a benefit to either, simply preference?

Comment: Cross apply behaves here identically, its power comes from more complex correlations and in some cenarios can result in the optimizer being able to push pedicates down to the seek/scan operators for correlations which can improve performance by reducing logical IO. Compare the queries together by viewing the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.product, price, color
FROM tabone t1
JOIN tabtwo t2
ON t1.product = t2.product
```

Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to SQL too lol